# Bootstrap submit button cannot post data in my phpmyadmin database and the textbox is messed up

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bootstrap-4

Boostrap submit form button would not connect onto my phpmyadmin database table. What am I missing here? Do I have the wrong pathway? Is my submit button modal incorrect? Please help.

## custom.js

kindly check if there are any errors in this part

```
// household show table
var table = $('.household-table').DataTable({
processing: true,
dom: 'lrtip',
serverSide: true,
ajax: config.routes.household,
columns: \[{
data: 'checkbox',
name: 'checkbox',
orderable: false,
searchable: false
},{
data: 'action',    
name: 'action',
orderable: false,
searchable: false

},{data: 'household_id',name: 'household_id', "visible": false,
},{data: 'household_no',name: 'household_no'
},{data: 'familyhead',name: 'familyhead' 
},{data: 'familymember',name: 'familymember'
},{data: 'familyincome',name: 'familyincome'
},{data: 'householdtype',name: 'householdtype'

},
]

});

//Household module CreateHousehold POPUP
$('#createhousehold').click(function() {
$('#submit').val("create-household");

$('#householdform').trigger("reset");
$('#modelHeading').html("Create Household Data");
$('#householdmodal').modal('show');
$('#household_no_err').html("");
$('#familyhead_err').html("");
$('#familymember_err').html("");
$('#familyincome_err').html("");
$('#householdtype').html("");

});

//Household module HouseholdEdit
$('body').on('click', '.editHousehold', function() {

var household_id = $(this).data('id');


$.get(config.routes.household + '/' + household_id + '/edit', function(data) {
    $('#modelHeading').html("Modify Household Data");
    $('#submit').val("Edit Household");
    $('#householdmodal').modal('show');
    $('#household_id').val(data.household_id);
    $('#household_no').val(data.household_no);
    $('#familyhead').val(data.familyhead);
    $('#familymember').val(data.familymember);
    $('#familyincome').val(data.familyincome);
    $('#householdtype').val(data.householdtype);

  //  $('#author').val(data.author);
});

});
//Household module viewmodal
$('body').on('click', '.viewhousehold', function() {
var household_id = $(this).data('id');

$.get(config.routes.household + '/' + household_id + '/edit', function(data) {

    $('#modelHeading').html("View Household Data");
    $('#submit').val("Edit Household");
    $('#householdviewmodal').modal('show');
    $('#household_idv').val(data.household_id);


    $('#household_no').val(data.household_no);
    $('#familyhead').val(data.familyhead);
    $('#familymember').val(data.familymember);
    $('#familyincome').val(data.familyincome);
    $('#householdtype').val(data.householdtype);





});

});

//BUTTOM SUBMIT MODAL
$('#submit').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
$(this).html('Save');
$(this).html('Submit');


$.ajax({
    data: $('#householdform').serialize(),
    url: config.routes.household_store,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == 1){
            $('#householdmodal').modal('hide');
            $('#householdform').trigger("reset");

            table.draw();
            }else{
                printErrorMsg(data.error);


            }
    }/*,
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);

        $('#submit').html('Save Changes');
    }
    */
});

});

//delete table
$('body').on('click', '.deletehousehold', function () {

var household_id = $(this).data("id");

if (confirm("Are You sure want to delete !")) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: config.routes.household_store +'/'+household_id,
        success: function (data) {
            table.draw();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
}

});

//Bulk Delete check all
$('#check-all').click(function(){
$('.checkBoxClass').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

// Bulk Delete Current Select
$('#bulkdelete').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var total=0;
$("input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked").each(function(){
    total += 1;
});


if (confirm("Number of Data to Delete: " + total)) {
$("input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked").each(function(){
    var household_id = $(this).data("id");


   $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: config.routes.household_store +'/'+household_id,
    success: function (data) {
        table.draw();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});

});

}

});
```

## web.php

and this as well since I am not really familiar with the routes of this.

```
//Household Module
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel\HouseholdsInfoController;

//Household Module
Route::get('/household', [HouseholdsInfoController::class, 'show']);
Route::resource('household', HouseholdsInfoController::class);
```

## HouseholdsInfoController.php

What else am I missing in this part and how will I be able to show the CRUD method?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//Models
use App\Models\households_info;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//Plugins
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use PDF;
class HouseholdsInfoController extends Controller
{

public function index(Request $request)
{
    if (!session()->has("user")) {
        return redirect("login");
    }
    
    $household = households_info::latest()->get();
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = households_info::latest()->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('checkbox', function($row){
                    $chk = '
                         <input type="checkbox" class="flat icheckbox_flat-green text-center checkBoxClass" id="checked"  name="ids" data-id="'.$row->household_id.'" name="table_records">';
                    return $chk;
                })
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->household_id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-info  btn-xs pr-4 pl-4 editHousehold"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i> </a>';
                    $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"   data-id="'.$row->household_id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pr-4 pl-4 deletehousehold"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i> </a>';
                    $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->household_id.'" data-original-title="View" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pr-4 pl-4 viewhousehold"><i class="fa fa-folder fa-lg"></i> </a>';
                     return $btn;
             })
               ->rawColumns(['checkbox','action'])
                ->make(true);





    }

    return view('pages.AdminPanel.households',[compact('household')]);
}
public function store(Request $request)
{


    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'household_no' => 'required',
        'familyhead' => 'required',
        'familymember' => 'required',
        'familyincome'  => 'required',
        'householdtype'  => 'required',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>0,'error'=>$validator->errors()]);
    }else{


    households_info::updateOrCreate(['household_id' => $request->household_id],
    ['household_no' => $request->household_no,
    'familyhead' => $request->familyhead,
    'familymember'=> $request->familymember,
    'familyincome'=>$request->familyincome,
    'householdtype'=>$request->householdtype]);

    return response()->json(['status'=>1,'success'=>'Household saved successfully.']);
    
    }
}
}
```

## households.blade.php

And what about this one? The submit button form modal cannot enter into my phpmyadmin database. What is the solution for this?

```
@extends('layouts.apps')
@section('content')
<div class="col-sm-12 text-left ">
<h1 class="border-bottom border-bot pt-3">Households Information</h1>
</div>
<div class="Household-Content main-wrapper col-sm-12 text-left h-100  pr-0 pl-0 " >
<div class="col-sm-12 pl-0 pr-0 search-bars" >
  <div class="topnav navbar navbar">
      <div>
     <button id="createhousehold" class="btn btn-success text-white " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#householdmodal">New Household <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
     <button id="bulkdelete" class="btn btn-danger text-white " style="margin-left:2px;" > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </div>


      <div class="modal fade" id="householdmodal" name="householdmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="household-modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading"></h5>
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                 <form id="householdform"  class="modal-input">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="household_id" id="household_id">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">




                        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-6" >
                          <label >Household No.</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="household_no" id="household_no" placeholder="Ex: 5" value="" required="">
                          <span id="household_no_err" class="text-danger error-text household_no_err"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                          <label >Family Head</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="familyhead" id="familyhead" placeholder="Ex: John Mark" value="" required="">
                          <span id="familyhead_err" class="text-danger error-text familyhead_err"></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-6" >
                          <label >Family Member</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="familymember" id="familymember" placeholder="Ex: Panlilio" value="" required="">
                          <span id="familymember_err" class="text-danger error-text familymember_err"></span>
                        </div>


                    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                       <div class="col-sm-6" >
                         <label >Family Income</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control"   name="familyincome" id="familyincome" placeholder="Ex: 123-45-678"  value="" required="">
                         <span id="familyincome_err" class="text-danger error-text familyincome_err"></span>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                         <label >Household Type</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="householdtype" id="householdtype"  placeholder="Ex: 09166041823" value="" required="">
                         <span id="householdtype_err" class="text-danger error-text householdtype_err"></span>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                </div>

            <!----------------
            -->
                </div>
                    <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                    <div class="item form-group">
                       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 offset-md-4">
                          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success household-button">Submit</button>
                          <a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-left: 4px;" >Cancel</a>
                          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer text-white">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="search-container">
        <input class="global_filter" type="text" id="global_filter" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-sm-12 text-left h-100  pr-0 pl-0 pt-2 pb-2 text-white" >
     <div class="row pl-4 pr-4   ">
        <div class="col-sm-12 border border-bot ">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row pt-4 pl-4 pr-4">
        <div  class=" col-sm-12 overflow-auto display-nones ">
           <table   class=" bulk_action dataTables_info table household-table datatable-element household table-striped jambo_table bulk_action text-center border dataTable no-footer">
              <thead>
                 <tr class="headings">
                    <th >
                        <input class="icheckbox_flat-green" type="checkbox"   id="check-all" >

                      </th>
                    <th class="column-title">Action</th>
                    <th class="column-title">Household_ID</th>
                    <th class="column-title">Household No.</th>
                    <th class="column-title">Family Head </th>


                    <th class="column-title">Family Income</th>

                    <th class="column-title">Household Type</th>


                    </th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              </tbody>
           </table>


        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>








<div class="modal fade" id="householdviewmodal" name="householdviewmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="household-modal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h5 class="modal-title" id="modelHeading">View Household Data</h5>



         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
      </div>




      <div class="modal-body">
         <form id="householdviewform"  class="modal-input">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="household_idv" id="household_idv">











































            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">





            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                <div class="col-sm-6" >
                  <label >Household No.</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="household_nov" name="household_nov"   readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                  <label >Family Head</label>
                  <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="familyheadv" name="familyheadv"  readonly >

                </div>
             
              </div>

              <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
                <div class="col-sm-6" >
                  <label >Family Member</label>
                  <input type="text"  readonly class="form-control" name="familymemberv" id="familymemberv" >

                </div>
              </div>






            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
               <div class="col-sm-6" >
                 <label >Family Income</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control"  readonly name="familyincomev" id="familyincomev" >

               </div>
              </div>


        </div>



             <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="first-name">Household Type
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                   <input type="text" id="householdtypev" readonly  name="householdtypev" class="form-control ">
                </div>
             </div>





        </div>



@endsection
```

Comment: So you're *posting* a form to the route `config.routes.household_store`, take a look in your web.php, you need a Route::post function to 'catch' that post and send it to your controller. Always when somethings not working from frontend, just open your Chrome Dev tools. Network tab and Console tab will help you. Network tab should give you a red error, check the error, response tab. Laravel should give you a log in storage/logs, check that log

Comment: How should the format be when needing a route::post function? Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you do a step by step process if possible?